# How to give an "alias" to a data type to later change it

Tags: c#, types, alias

First of all, an example, but please take it with a pinch of salt, don't discuss if I should use one type or the other, the focus is on the possibility of changing the data type:

*Let's assume we are creating an application for working with money and population. We decide that we will **represent the money quantities with the type Uint16**, because a priori seems reasonable that the size will be enough and that we will not work with negative values.*

*After quite some time, **we realize that we are going to need a different type** since we will now need negative values, or higher amounts than can be represented by Uint16, so we want to use Int32 instead for money calculations. However, there are other quantities represented by Uint16 in our code (for example, population), so we can't just substitute all uses of Uint16 into Int32.*

So the question is: **how can I refer to a datatype for specific cases, so that I am able to easily change the datatype being used, without affecting unrelated uses of that same datatype**?

Note that I am thinking about this problem without creating a *class Money*, but if you consider that's the way it should be done, I would also gladly like to read your reasoning for it.

Comment: "we can't just substitute all uses of Uint16 into Int32" you wouldn't want to do that, anyway. Any sort of refactoring you're going to need to do is going to require a human with something resembling a brain to review.

Comment: You mean that because the types will behave differently, it's not safe to just do a type rename without reviewing all uses of the data?

Comment: @Mr.Crystal more that the approach of "let's replace all instances of _$someType_ with _$someOtherType_" is not something you're going to want to do, anyway.

Comment: If you want to be able to vary the representation while maintaining a consistent interface then define your own data type. In this case it sounds like a struct might be suitable.

Comment: This question seems too abstract to me. Can you please provide a concrete example? I don't see why you couldn't just change `Uint16 BankBalance { get; set; }` to `Int32 BankBalance { get; set; }`. You choose types for specific properties, fields, return values, arguments, etc. If you have to change those later, then you change them where the changes are needed. I must be missing something in your question, so an actual code example might help.

Comment: Otherwise, creating your own class would allow you to customize the internal processing or even the external API without requiring clients to change the type name. However, changing an external API would likely require some changes in the code that use that type.

Comment: Creating a class seemed like an overkill at the beginning for my case, but using simply a type like decimal or int definitely won't work for me. I think creating a struct like @Lee suggested would be the best option.

Comment: Well, you can create an alias for a type and then change what that alias refers to later (i.e. `using Number = System.Int32;`, which can later be changed to `using Number = System.Decimal;`, then you can use it with `Number myNum = 1;`). I added an answer below describing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to alias a type is to do it in the `using` section. You can give a custom name to just about any type, and then use that name in your code instead.

You can do this with built-in types if you just want to switch from `uint` to `decimal`:

```
using Number = System.Int32;
```

and you would use it like:

```
Number myNumber = 1;
```

Then later, if you wanted to change all instances of `Number` to be a `decimal` instead, you simply do:

```
using Number = System.Decimal;
```

---

You can do this with custom types as well, for example let's say we have two classes, `Bank1` and `Bank2`. `Bank1` has a `uint` property called `Balance`, while `Bank2` has a `decimal` property of the same name. We can create an alias named `Bank` that we use in our code, and have it reference the type `Bank1`, and then we can instantiate an instance of it and assign an `int` to the balance.

To highlight that different classes are being called each time, I've changed their `ToString` overrides so that the `decimal` balance is displayed with a decimal point:

```
using Bank = Test.Bank1;

namespace Test
{
    public class Bank1
    {
        public uint Balance { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() => $"Balance is {Balance}";
    }

    public class Bank2
    {
        public decimal Balance { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() => $"Balance is {Balance:N2}";
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bank = new Bank();
            bank.Balance = 100;

            Console.WriteLine(bank);

            GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Now, later we can change what that alias is referring to without breaking our code:

```
using Bank = Test.Bank2;  // Just change what the alias refers to here
```

[image]

Note that you will still have to go and fix any compilation errors that may occur after changing the type, depending on what changes you made.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was talking about! However, if I would have a lot of files/classes making use of Bank, I would need to add a "using" directive in all of them?

Comment: Yes, I believe you would have to have it defined in each file where you want to use the alias. But there may be some way around it, I'm not 100% certain.